# Maximum value of $f(x)$ if $f(x)+f\left(1/x\right)=x$

Tags: functions, proof-verification

What is the maximum value of $f(x)$ if $f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=x$ for all $x$ in the domain of this real valued function?

Now $f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=x$ and by symmetry $f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{x}$. Therefore $x=\frac{1}{x}$ $\implies$ $x=1$ or $-1$.
Does it mean that the domain of the function is only $1$ or $-1$ ?
And therefore substituting $x=1$ in the equation we get maximum value of $f(x)$ as $1/2$?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: It is a strange question, isn't it? But your logic looks impeccable to me. The only problem with the question is that it implies, without stating it explicitly, that $x$ is in the domain of $f$ if and only if $1/x$ is.

Comment: @TonyK, true, but I think since it's given that $f(x) + f(1/x) = x$ for all $x$ in the domain, then we can safely conclude that $1/x$ is also in the domain, since otherwise the (only) given information wouldn't make sense and would be unusable.

Comment: The condition given is equivalent to $x=1$ or $x=-1$. Thus, the maximum value is $\dfrac 12$ unless you know something about $f(0)$, which cant be found out given the limited information.

Comment: If f(x)=x/2 then x is +1 or -1 however you can also say that f(x)=1/(2*x) and get the same answer. I think the solution lies with how you said f(x)+f(1/x)=x=1/x. The solution for x=1/x is that x^2=1 or x=+1 or -1. 

Also, f(x) could be -x/2 or -1/(2*x) and then you have a flip of where the max value is, x=-1 would cause the max.

Comment: @tilper: I think Apurv's comment illustrates my point very neatly! Apurv, $0$ can't be in the domain of $f$, because then we would have $f(0)+f(1/0)=0$.

Comment: If 1/(sqrt(1/x))=sqrt(x) then you could say that f(x)=2*i/sqrt(x)-1/2 and then the only solution for x is -1 and the max for f(-1)=3/2

Comment: @TonyK, I agree that $0$ can't be in the domain of $f$ for precisely that reason, but I still don't see how the lack of explicit mentioning of $x \in \text{domain} \iff 1/x \in \text{domain}$ is a problem since to me it's pretty clear from the only piece of given info.

Comment: @tipler: Well it wasn't clear to Apurv, was it?

Comment: OK,  to be fair, there are two pieces I guess.  $f$ is real-valued and $f(x) + f(1/x) = x$.  And I bring this up because, @WindowsNT, $f(x) = 2i/\sqrt x - 1/2$ is not real-valued and doesn't satisfy the hypotheses of the problem.  Also, $f(x) = \pm x/2$ and $f(x) = \pm 1/(2x)$ both don't work because they don't satisfy $f(x) + f(1/x) = x$ for all $x$ in the domain.

Comment: @TonyK, sounds like an Apurv problem to me.  :P   $\quad$  More generally, not being clear to someone doesn't really mean anything.  Algebraic topology wasn't very clear to me, but that's not Allen Hatcher's fault.  Kind of.

Comment: My two cents: By the wording and by the logic that $f(x) + f(1/x) = f(1/x) + f(x) = x = 1/x$.  I am thinking the *point* of the question was to determine the domain which cannot contain anything other than {-1,1}.  ... Actually, I'm going to quibble:  If the domain isn't specified that doesn't mean the domain *has* to be the most comprehensive.  It's possible for the function's domain to be {-1} is which case the maximum value is -1/2.  I'll rule out the domain being the empty set because... well, "real-valued"...

Answer (score 3):

Most of this has already been said in the comments.

Your argument is correct that if $x$ is in the domain of $f$, then $x=1$ or $x=-1$. The question does not specify what the domain of $f$ is, so there are four possibilities for the domain: $\varnothing$, $\{1\}$, $\{-1\}$, or $\{1,-1\}$.

You computed that if $f$ is defined at $x=1$ then $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$. Similarly, if $f$ is defined at $x=-1$ then $f(-1)=-\frac{1}{2}$. So we have three possibilities for the maximum value:

- If the domain of $f$ is $\{1\}$ or $\{1,-1\}$, then $\max f=\frac{1}{2}$.
- If the domain of $f$ is $\{-1\}$, then $\max f=-\frac{1}{2}$.
- If the domain of $f$ is $\varnothing$, then $\max f$ is not defined (some people write $\max f=-\infty$ in this case).